# Unable to create a react js application using npm

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

After installing nodejs, while creating a new react application I am facing the following issue.

I've tried reinstalling nodejs and maybe that is not the solution.

> ```
> C:\Users\abhis>npm i create-react-app
> npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\abhis\package.json'
> npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\abhis\package.json'
> npm WARN abhis No description
> npm WARN abhis No repository field.
> npm WARN abhis No README data
> npm WARN abhis No license field.
>
> + create-react-app@3.4.1
> added 53 package from 35 contributors, updated 1 package and audited 166 packages in 18.807s
>
> 6 packages are looking for funding
>  run `npm fund` for details
>
> found 0 vulnerabilities
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there is no `package.json` file, therefore you can't install (`npm i`) packages.

To create a `package.json` file try `npm init`.

However, if you want to create new react app using `create-react-app`, just execute: `npx create-react-app my-app`.

Comment: After execution of npx create-react-app my-app. instead of creation of an application i am facing this issue 

 core-js@2.6.11 postinstall C:\Users\abhis\Desktop\web\my-app\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js@3.6.5 postinstall C:\Users\abhis\Desktop\web\my-app\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js-pure@3.6.5 postinstall C:\Users\abhis\Desktop\web\my-app\node_modules\core-js-pure
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

Comment: I found something that might help: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8441

Comment: This one looks same. but i am unable to solve it from the link. can you please help me in detail.

Comment: Can you give more information? Plus, did you executed it in an empty directory?

Comment: yes, i executed in an empty directory. what all info you need?

Comment: C:\Users\abhis>npm config set script-shell C:\Program Files\git\bin\bash.exe

C:\Users\abhis>npm config set script-shell "C:\Program Files\git\bin\bash.exe" I tried executing these commands.

Answer (score 0):

you have installed package successfully,

to create app, here is the 2 approach you can use

after installing create react app,

`npm init react-app my-app`

another approach is,

`npx create-react-app my-app`

also, have a look at official documentation.
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/

Comment: After execution of npx create-react-app my-app. instead of creation of an application i am facing this issue 


 core-js@2.6.11 postinstall C:\Users\abhis\Desktop\web\my-app\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"



> core-js@3.6.5 postinstall C:\Users\abhis\Desktop\web\my-app\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"



> core-js-pure@3.6.5 postinstall C:\Users\abhis\Desktop\web\my-app\node_modules\core-js-pure

> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

Comment: which npm version you have ?

Comment: i tried the first approach, no i got an error similar to this one 

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8441

which was suggested by @SomoKRoces. can you please help me in detail? i am unable to do that.

my npm version is: 6.14.6.

Comment: have you tried this solution ?  ```npm config set script-shell "C:\\Program Files\\git\\bin\\bash.exe" ```

Answer (score 0):

To create a react app using create-react-app you have 2 options:

- install globally create-react-app using this command: npm install --global create-react-app and then create your react project with: create-react-app project_name
- the other option which is the recommanded one is by directly creating you app using this command: npx create-react-app project_name.
  source: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/

using npm i create-react-app didn't work for you because you don't have a package.json like @SomoKRoceS mentioned.

Comment: After execution of npx create-react-app my-app. instead of creation of an application i am facing this issue 


 core-js@2.6.11 postinstall C:\Users\abhis\Desktop\web\my-app\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"



> core-js@3.6.5 postinstall C:\Users\abhis\Desktop\web\my-app\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"



> core-js-pure@3.6.5 postinstall C:\Users\abhis\Desktop\web\my-app\node_modules\core-js-pure

> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

Comment: @abhishek gattineni  which npm version do you have ?

Comment: the version i am using is 6.14.6

Comment: try this, maybe it will help you https://dev.to/gouthamigou/comment/n2do

Comment: this problem is same as mine. There they used npm cache clear --force, even after executing this command nothing positive turned out.

Comment: did you try to uninstall node js and then download nodjs 32 bits ?

Comment: I get the same message as you today when I cloned my project from github but everything works fine for me when I runned it, I think you don't have to worry about it